# sqlmap UNION injection

Tags: sql, code-injection, sqlmap

I was debugging some UNION injection techniques with sqlmap and was wondering what are the variables I can use in the payloads.xml that will use number value in order instead of "NULL" and/or a static union character? Seems like the creator of sqlmap created this tool to be purposely ineffective so that websites aren't easily hacked so I was just wondering instead of typing out manually for each column number order e.g. 1,2,3 then 1,2,3,4 then 1,2,3,4,5 and so forth, what are the variables I can use or anybody have an example I can use in payloads.xml that I can play with? Penetration testing my websites and make sure they're solid. Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlmap UNION injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708811/sqlmap-union-injection)

Comment: yeah, apologies.... Internet is real slow didn't know if it posted or not

Comment: Would you please delete one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mark * inside your request (GET , POST) , and it will be the injection point used .

you also can use a prefix or postfix to your attack , using --prefix and --suffix

and salmap will take care of the rest .

you can check the full usage from here

https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage